# PDF417 type of Barcode is not able to scanned in below iPhone X from Firebase MLkit

Tags: ios, firebase-mlkit

I am using Firebase MLKIT for scanning Barcode in IOS.
PDF417 type of Barcode is not able to scan in IOS device below Iphone x.

Comment: just look at the different type of barcode supported by MLKIT. For PDF417 scanning u can use https://github.com/PDF417/pdf417-ios . also check for barcode type available for scan

Comment: do you have some progress here??

Comment: can you share an example of the PDF417 code that is not being recognized? Just want to note that:
PDF417 is a very dense barcode. The input image needs to be big enough for a valid detection. See size guideline here, https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/read-barcodes#input-image-guidelines